# Can't center nav elements responsively using css and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

What I want is to have my navbar-brand centered responsively on all platforms and my nav items/links, including the navbar-toggler positioned on right.

Right now it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBEpH.png). on large screens. And I can't get it centered at all.

But if I shrink it down below 991px dimension, the navbar does centered, albeit strange and is not properly aligned with the items.

[On smaller screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT6Ev.png)

I am using bootstrap alone and my css file doesn't have anything in it yet.

I've tried overwriting it on my css file but it won't center at all. I've read bootstrap's docs but I can't seem to make it work.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the navbar-expand-lg, because it affects the nav-links and the navbar-brand (centers it) upon shrinking below 991px dimension.

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: what about just adding me-5 or pe-5 to center links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.navbar-brand` does not align with the `.nav-link`s due to the space occupied by the `.navbar-toggler`. With the help of [BS's position utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/position/) you can take the `.navbar-toggler`'s size out of the equation. You need to add `.position-relative` to the `.container-fluid` and `.position-absolute.top-0.end-0` to the `.navbar-toggler`. The toggler will be removed from the flow and positioned at the top right corner, leaving everything else centered within the container width.

> Elements that are relatively positioned remain in the normal flow of the document. In contrast, an element that is absolutely positioned is taken out of the flow; thus, other elements are positioned as if it did not exist. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, it is positioned relative to the ICB (initial containing block — see also the [W3C definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)), which is the containing block of the document's root element.
>
> --https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute_positioning

You can have everything centered on two lines in the expanded view by adding [`.flex-wrap`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#wrap) to the container, and `.w-100` to the brand. The brand will take the full width, with centered text, and the `.navbar-collapse` will wrap to next line with contents centered thanks to [`.justify-content-center`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navs-tabs/#horizontal-alignment).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center position-relative flex-wrap">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto w-100" href="#">brand</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler position-absolute top-0 end-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind telling me why use `.position-relative` `.justify-content-center`, `.flex-wrap` on the `.container-fluid` class?

Comment: `.position-relative` is so that the `.navbar-toggler` will be absolute positioned within it, `.flex-wrap` allows the nav to break to the next line. `.justify-content-center` wasn't necessary that was an early attempt and forgot to remove it, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark position-sticky">
        <div class="container-fluid text-center">
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
                aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse me-5" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark position-sticky">
        <div class="container-fluid text-center">
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
                aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-center" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In 'collapse-navbar' use these  " d-flex justify-content-center" classes to center it on large screen and for collapse make it perfectly center on small screen add "me-5" class in 'collapse-navbar'. I hope it will help. :)

Comment: Sorry I don't think that would solve my problem here. 

First of all, what it does it center the links on large screens <img src="https://imgur.com/a/dy6EooX>. Which is not what I want to center as I've asked in my question.

Secondly, it puts the navbar-nav in a neutral state of being "collapsed", meaning it cannot be hidden anymore even if you click the nav-toggle.

Yes, it somehow aligned the navbar-brand along with the links. But it is "aligned" not "centered" on screen, for reference, see this image <img src="https://imgur.com/a/i2Cf9qr">